# display textboxes centered inside a skewed rectangle

Tags: html, css

How do I put centered textboxes inside each of the colored boxes in the image below?

**Update:** As requested, I'm adding my embarrassing attempt. I know it's bad, but I don't do design so I am kind of lost.

p.s. thanks for the down votes!

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrhe3/

```
table{width: 585px; height: 585px; background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uknk9.png');} 
input{background-color: transparent; width: 100%; border-style:none; font-size: 32px;}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="center"><input type="number" id="number" value="1" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><input type="number" id="number"  value="2" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="left"><input type="number" id="number" value="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td valign="top" align="center"><input type="number" id="number" value="4" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

[image: hazwoper sign]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution over here http://jsfiddle.net/ZC2bd/46/ but I'm sure you haven't looked for enough ;) google is your friend

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
  <input id="top" type="text" />
  <input id="left" type="text" />
  <input id="right" type="text" />
  <input id="bottom" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#background{
    display: block;
    width: 597px;
    height: 597px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uknk9.png');
}
#top{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 135px 0 0 224px;
}
#left{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 290px 0 0 70px;
}
#right{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 290px 0 0 380px;
}
#bottom{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 435px 0 0 230px;
}​
```

Concerning the HTML part it's pretty explicit, there is one container which contains four inputs.

In the CSS file, I've set your image in background of my container with fixed width and height.
Then I've created four id's for the inputs all with the property `position` set to [absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

The absolute attribute allows you to set the position of an element taking as reference the parent element, here the `<div id="background">`.
So since you know its size you can position your elements with the `margin` prooperty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You [don't need to sign your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) (your name, and a link to your user-page is already there), but it'd be nice if you could post the code from your demo in your answer and, perhaps, explain how it works, if such might be needed.

Comment: hmm... what is this "Google" you speak of? Can you post a link for me?

Comment: While you might rather not use absolute positioning like Aymeric's solution, it is much less clunky than a solution involving using a LOT of divs to "section" off your image into slices. (Which I can show you if you have the stomach for).